# Floating image right does not work in mPDF. Is there another way to do this?

Tags: html, css, image, pdf, mpdf

I tried to right align an image in HTML with CSS and to convert it to a PDF file. mPDF seems to fail. The image is on the left side of the document. Is there another way to do this than float: right?

```
<img id='head' src='test.jpg' style='float: right;margin-right: 0px'>
```

Comment: https://mpdf.github.io/about-mpdf/limitations.html

Answer (score 0):

try with one wrapper

```
<div style='float: right;margin-right: 0px'>
   <img id='head' src='test.jpg'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was that the img tag was in a table and mPDF doesn't support floating on tables or children of tables